# Importing post tags into Wordpress with the WXR format

Tags: wordpress

I'm moving from a legacy system over to Wordpress. I've read that the WXR import format isn't officially documented, but that [this sample can be used as documentation](https://code.google.com/p/google-blog-converters-appengine/source/browse/trunk/samples/wordpress-sample.wxr).

With that said, why isn't this post tagged with "awesome"? The awesome tag is created in the top of the WXR file with

```
<tag>
    <term_idname>2781</term_idname>
    <tag_slug>awesome</tag_slug>
    <tag_name>
        <![CDATA[awesome]]>
    </tag_name>
</tag>
```

And I find it in the backend after importing. The post is however not tagged. No posts are tagged. But all tags are imported, just with 0 children. This is how I try to import the post:

```
<item>
    <title>The title is awesome</title>
    <link>http://example.com/awesome</link>
    <creator>This Ramvi</creator>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://example.com/awesome</guid>
    <description></description>
    <encoded>
        <![CDATA[<p>Very short post
        </p>]]>
    </encoded>
    <post_id>843156</post_id>
    <post_date>2014-10-22 10:34</post_date>
    <post_date_gmt>2014-10-22 08:34</post_date_gmt>
    <comment_status>open</comment_status>
    <ping_status>open</ping_status>
    <post_name>Really awesome post</post_name>
    <status>publish</status>
    <category domain="tag">
        <![CDATA[awesome]]>
    </category>
    <post_type>post</post_type>
</item>
```

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty much in the sample linked to in the question. You need two lines to add tags to a post:

```
<category domain="tag"><![CDATA[NewTag]]></category>
<category domain="tag" nicename="newtag"><![CDATA[NewTag]]></category>
```